# Passing values from SOQL

Tags: trigger, soql

I have this as part of an initial trigger on before update. I want to pass the value coming out of the query done on **actualEvent** (OwnerId) into a the `Set<ID> userId = new Set<Id>();`. 
The way I'm doing this is not working for the loop I do for the **actual.keyset()**
So, how can I pass the value (OwnerId) from my SOQL query done to the Events to my set of ids?

```
 Map<Id, Event> actualEvent = new Map<Id, Event>
 ([SELECT Id, OwnerId,Activity_Total_Duration_Time__c, Activity_Cost__c, Status_Event__c
 FROM Event WHERE Status_Event__c ='Completed'
 AND Id =: Trigger.old]);

List<EventRelation> whoRelations = new List<EventRelation>([SELECT Id, Relation.Name, Status
                                   FROM EventRelation
                                   WHERE EventId = : actualEvent.keySet()]);

Set<Id> userId = new Set<Id>();


for(Id id: actualEvent.keyset()){
    userId.add(id.OwnerId);

}
```

Thanks in advanced and sorry form my previous question, it was not very clear. I hope this one is better, if not let me know please. 
Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more specific in what you are trying to achieve? The `Trigger` context already gives you access to the fields without you needing to query again. And triggers must be written to work with multiple records so loops are always involved. Generally it is best to declare the variables inside the loop too as that is the only place they will have useful values.

Comment: What I'm trying  to achieve is to get values from the fields that are returning from a SOQL query, make certain calculations and update the initial fields that came from the SOQL query and set those new values back to the event page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`actualEvent` is a declared as a `Map<Id, Event>`, in the following bit of code you are iterating over the **keys** which is a `Set<Id>`:

```
for(Id id: actualEvent.keyset())
{
    userId.add(id.OwnerId);
}
```

The`Id` object does not have an `OwnerId` property, the `Event` object does, so what you actually want to do is iterrate over the **values** of your Map which is a `List<Event>` if you want to access properties of the `Event` objects:

```
for(Event anEvent : actualEvent.values())
{
    userId.add(anEvent.OwnerId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to store the value in a separate variable. You are already storing the value in a List variable and can you that later in the code.

Comment: In the case of the OwnerId I want to add that id to a List.
`List<Id> userId = new List<Id>;`
So how can I add the OwnerId from my SOQL to my userId list?

Comment: yes you have to make use of a for loop to do that. :)

Comment: SFCD_MJ did you intend to comment on the question ? unlike forums answers on stackexchange sites are meant to provide a definite answer or solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: Hello again, 
Will this be ok?
`for(Event e: actualEvent.values() ){e.OwnerId = eventOwner;  userId.add(eventOwner);}` 

I received no errors from eclipse. Please let me know.
Thanks.